# Enredo con ciclo causa que reciba todos los correos que se envian al primer correo en mi base de datos

Tags: bucles, phpmailer

tengo una base de datos la cual tiene correos.

Hago una consulta para mandar por Gmail los correos a mis usuarios usando PHPMailer
y la consulta funciona pero en el primer correo registrado "el mio" yo recibo todos los correos de todas las personas a las que le envío el correo electrónico
Todas las personas reciben su correo , pero se me dificulta bastante ya que mi BD crece y si vuelvo a hacer el proceso que ya tiene mas de 4000 registros voy a recibir en mi correo todos y cada unos de los correos.

Estoy usando el Between de sql para hacer envios paulatinamente ya que se me cae el servidor.

Aquí mi código

```
<?php

$host_db = "";

 $user_db = "";

 $pass_db = "";

 $db_name = "";

 $tbl_name = "";



 $conexion = new mysqli($host_db, $user_db, $pass_db, $db_name);
 $conexion2 = new mysqli($host_db, $user_db, $pass_db, $db_name);


 if ($conexion->connect_error) {

 die("La conexion fall贸: " . $conexion->connect_error);

}




$consulta =  "SELECT * FROM correo_usuarios WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 100";
$consulta2 = "SELECT * FROM correo_usuarios WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 100";


if ($resultado2 = mysqli_query($conexion2, $consulta2)) {


    while ($fila2 = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado2)) {
       //  printf ("%s %s %s %s\n", $fila2[0], $fila2[1], $fila2[2], $fila2[3]);

    }


    mysqli_free_result($resultado2);
}

/*

require ("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");

//Envio de correo electronico al usuario

$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = ""; 
$mail->Port = 465;// or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = ""; 
$mail->Password = "";    
$mail->SetFrom("",""); 
$mail->Subject = "Tu pana Virtual te desea Exito";


$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

if ($resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta)) {

    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado)) {
        $mail->addAddress($fila[2]);

        $mail->Body = "         

hola ".$fila[1]." te deseamos exito en este día 

                  ";
        $mail->Send();
    }

    mysqli_free_result($resultado);

}
*/

mysqli_close($conexion);
mysqli_close($conexion2);

?>
```

Los correos funcionan y las busquedas tambien . 
Lo que no entiendo es porque el primer contacto recibe el correo que se le envía a todos los demas...

Comment: Ya te conteste :(

Answer (score 1):

Estas haciendo un mail->addAddress y
reutilizado el mismo objeto mail en todas las iteración es del loop
 por lo que
 el primer mail tiene tu primer contacto
el segundo tiene el primero y el segundo y
 el tercero el primero, segundo y tercero
.Add significa agrega.

```
require ("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");

//Envio de correo electronico al usuario

// crear un obj mail nuevo con toda la configuracion 
function createMail(){
    $mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->Host = ""; 
    $mail->Port = 465;// or 587
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = ""; 
    $mail->Password = "";    
    $mail->SetFrom("",""); 
    $mail->Subject = "Tu pana Virtual te desea Exito";
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    return $mail;
}
if ($resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta)) {

    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado)) {
        // al crear un nuevo mail en cada iteracion no se agrega el address al anterior
        $mail = createMail();
        $mail->addAddress($fila[2]);

        $mail->Body = "         

hola ".$fila[1]." te deseamos exito en este día 

                  ";
        $mail->Send();
    }

}
```

Comment: puedes ayudarlo con un bloque de código??? sera mas fácil para el OP entender el error y la solución... date una vuelta por [answer] para mas información...

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/161547)

Comment: @Marc claro que si, el problema de OP es citando "Lo que no entiendo es porque el primer contacto recibe el correo que se le envía a todos los demas..." esa es justamente la explicacion que se da

Comment: @VíctorHugoTirado hecho!!